# How to animate the following quicksort algorithm in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn more about programing and sorting algorithms in general and i wanted to create an animation of a quicksort algorithm using div's with different heights. I've created the sorting algorithm.
Running the code snippet will help you understand what i'm trying to do.
Here is the code but after the sorting is done it only shows the final result and not the whole process:

```js
function createColumns() {
  $('.column').remove();
  var content = $('#content');
  var columnNumber = $('input:text').val();
  var columnWidth = ((content.width() * 99 / 100) / columnNumber) + 'px';
  for (var i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++) {
    var randomColor = '#' + ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6);
    var columnHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (columnNumber - 1)) + 1;
    $('<div/>', {
      'class': 'column'
    }).css({
      'height': columnHeight + 'px',
      'width': columnWidth,
      'background-color': randomColor
    }).appendTo(content);
  }
}


function quickSort(columns, left, right) {
  var index;
  if (columns.length > 1) {
    index = partition(columns, left, right);
    if (left < (index - 1)) {
      quickSort(columns, left, (index - 1));
    }
    if (index < right) {
      quickSort(columns, index, right);
    }
  }

  return columns;

}

function partition(columns, left, right) {
  var pivot = $(columns[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)]),
    i = left,
    j = right;
  while (i <= j) {
    while ($(columns[i]).height() < pivot.height()) {
      i++
    }
    while ($(columns[j]).height() > pivot.height()) {
      j--;
    }
    if (i <= j) {
      swap(columns, i, j);
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }
  return i;
}

function swap(columns, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
  var temp, visualTemp;

  visualTemp = columns[secondIndex];
  $(columns[firstIndex]).insertAfter($(columns[secondIndex]));
  $(visualTemp).insertBefore($(columns[firstIndex + 1]));

  temp = columns[firstIndex];
  columns[firstIndex] = columns[secondIndex];
  columns[secondIndex] = temp;
}


$('input').change(function() {
  createColumns();
});

$('#quickSort').click(function() {
  var columns = $('.column');
  var left = 0,
    right = columns.length - 1;

  quickSort(columns, left, right);
});

createColumns();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number of columns: <input type="text" value="100" />
<div id="content">
</div>
<input type="button" id="quickSort" name="QuickSort" value="Quick Sort">
```

Comment: When I try to run the snippet it keeps telling my createColumns(); is undefined, did you forget to put some code in your snippet?

Comment: The code is probably executed way to fast for you to be able to see the animation. Try adding some kind of delay between steps, for example using a `setTimeout` for 100 milliseconds each step. This will probably be enough to see the results

Comment: @VlassisFo I am looking at the code and createColumns(); is called at the bottom of the page but it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I fixed it! @B.Cratty

Comment: This is not a full solution, but an approach you might consider.  Inside `swap`, add some code that appends the pair of indices to a running list.  (You could use a parameter passed through `quicksort` and `partition` or a more global variable.)  Run the sort, and only then do some animation using this list of swaps.  It's a lot less intrusive than trying to modify your algorithm to incorporate animation delays.  Of course I leave the animation up to you! :-)

Comment: If you are looking for something to reference to get some guidance, I was able to find this [Sorting.Js](https://github.com/jcjohnson/sorting.js/tree/master)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not quite animated, you can slow the sorting process down a bit if you wrap the internals of your `quickSort` function in a setTimeout with a small delay (i've chosen 750ms) to see each step.

```js
function createColumns() {
  $('.column').remove();
  var content = $('#content');
  var columnNumber = $('input:text').val();
  var columnWidth = ((content.width() * 99 / 100) / columnNumber) + 'px';
  for (var i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++) {
    var randomColor = '#' + ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6);
    var columnHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (columnNumber - 1)) + 1;
    $('<div/>', {
      'class': 'column'
    }).css({
      'height': columnHeight + 'px',
      'width': columnWidth,
      'background-color': randomColor
    }).appendTo(content);
  }
}


function quickSort(columns, left, right) {
  var index;

  setTimeout(function() {


    if (columns.length > 1) {
      index = partition(columns, left, right);
      if (left < (index - 1)) {

        quickSort(columns, left, (index - 1));
      }
      if (index < right) {
        quickSort(columns, index, right);
      }
    }

    return columns;
  }, 750);

}

function partition(columns, left, right) {
  var pivot = $(columns[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)]),
    i = left,
    j = right;
  while (i <= j) {
    while ($(columns[i]).height() < pivot.height()) {
      i++
    }
    while ($(columns[j]).height() > pivot.height()) {
      j--;
    }
    if (i <= j) {
      swap(columns, i, j);
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }
  return i;
}

function swap(columns, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
  var temp, visualTemp;

  visualTemp = columns[secondIndex];
  $(columns[firstIndex]).insertAfter($(columns[secondIndex]));
  $(visualTemp).insertBefore($(columns[firstIndex + 1]));

  temp = columns[firstIndex];
  columns[firstIndex] = columns[secondIndex];
  columns[secondIndex] = temp;
}


$('input').change(function() {
  createColumns();
});

$('#quickSort').click(function() {
  var columns = $('.column');
  var left = 0,
    right = columns.length - 1;

  quickSort(columns, left, right);
});

createColumns();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number of columns: <input type="text" value="100" />
<div id="content">
</div>
<input type="button" id="quickSort" name="QuickSort" value="Quick Sort">
```

Comment: I can't believe it was this easy all along. Great answer!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @SzucsEduard let me know if you need help with anything else